# How to submit POST requests if form is a value of innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, php, html, dom

Every time I access $_POST on the other page, there is no value. How do we submit post request if the form is in innerHTML?

```js
function edit(firstname){
      var firstname_old = document.getElementById("firstname-div")
      //Set id="FirstName" to your input field
      firstname_old.innerHTML= 'First Name:<input type="text" id="FirstName" name="firstname" value="'+ firstname +'">';
      }
```

```html
<form class="" action="summary.php" method="post">
      <div id="firstname-div">
        <?php echo "First Name: $firstname<br>"; ?>
      </div>
      <button type="button" onclick="edit('<?php echo $firstname ?>')">edit</button><br>

      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
```

Comment: what does `var_dump($_POST);` show you?

Comment: The code snippet here basically works, if you ignore that the PHP tags look weird … once I click edit, enter a first name "foobar" and submit, then my browser network panel shows a POST request that sends `firstname: foobar` and `submit: submit` … so, problem not reproducible.

Answer (score 1):

When you are not in "edit-mode" your're putting out just a text.

```
<?php echo "First Name: $firstname<br>"; ?>
```

Thist text is inside the form which will be submitted but its not a form-field! To achieve what you want (deliver the content of "firstname" via ajax) you need a "hidden field".
So you put the same value which is shown in the text to a hidden input like this.

```
<form class="" action="summary.php" method="post">
  <div id="firstname-div">
    <?php echo "First Name: $firstname<br>"; ?>
  </div>
  <button type="button" onclick="edit('<?php echo $firstname ?>')">edit</button><br>
  <input type="hidden" name="firstname" value="'<?php echo $firstname ?>'">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

What I understand that you want to display a textbox to edit the name on clicking the edit button . Here is one solution for that:-

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#edit").click(function(){
        document.getElementById("firstname-div").style.display = "none" ;
        document.getElementById("firstname-div-edit").style.display = "block" ;
    });
});
</script>

<HTML>
<form class="" action="summary.php" method="post">
    <div id="firstname-div">
    <?php echo "First Name: $firstname<br>"; ?>
    </div>
    <div id="firstname-div-edit" style="display:none;">
    <input type="text" name="firstname" value="'<?php echo $firstname ?>'">
    </div>
    <button type="button" id="edit">edit</button><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
</HTML>
```

Check and let me know if it works for you or not.